# Maven access system properties within pom

Tags: maven

While running a maven application I am passing a systemproperty `-DconfFolder=c:/config`. Within the pom how do I access this value? I want the resource plugin to move some file to this confFolder.

Answer (score 8):

You can access this value with `${confFolder}` inside `pom.xml`.

[Maven Properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties).

Comment: @MaxHohenegger Thanks for the link, I update the answer.